# Windows named pipe - ReadLineAsync is executed only when server application is stopped

Tags: c#, windows, named-pipes, libuv

I have a server program in the C language and the UI application in C#.

I have created the pipe using **libuv** in the server application. When I try to read data from the pipe using the C# application, the `ReadAsync` function is not invoked until the server application is stopped.

I have another C program to read the data from the pipe, and that one reads data as soon as server sends the data into the pipe.

Do you know why the C# application is not reading data form the pipe until the server is stopped?

C# function to connect to the pipe:

```cs
async protected Task ConnectPipesAsync()
{
    await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        eventClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(localPipeServer, eventPipe, PipeDirection.In);
        await eventClient.ConnectAsync(ServiceConnectTimeout);
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to the pipe");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        semaphoreSlim.Release();
        Console.WriteLine("Could not connect to the service. {0}", ex.Message);
    }
    semaphoreSlim.Release();
}
```

C# function to read from the pipe:

```cs
async public void StartReadingFromPipeSync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start reading from pipe ... ");
    try
    {
        StreamReader eventReader = new StreamReader(eventClient);
        while (true)
        {
            if (eventReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                break;
            }
            string respAsString = null;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for event data ... ");
                respAsString = await eventReader.ReadLineAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Received data - {0}", respAsString);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR caught in readMessageAsync: {0}", ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("unepxected error: {0}", ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Can we forcefully flush data from the c program after the `uv_write` function (libuv)?

Comment: Are you sure it's not invoked? `ReadLine` completes only when it receives a newline character. If the server never sends such a character `ReadLine` will never complete, unless the server closes the stream.

Comment: What does your *server* do? Does it send newlines?

Comment: I tried to replace the ReadLineAsync with ReadBlockAsync, still client application didnt read the data. You are right, the server does not send the new line character, but since the ReadBlock also didnt read the data, I suppose the issue must be something else.


```
                       await eventReader.ReadBlockAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
```

Comment: My server sends json data as string. It does not append new line at the end, it will have the null character at the end

Comment: `ReadLine` expects a newline. It's the same in every language, every OS. When reading a line, you read everything up to the next newline character

Comment: Thanks a lot @PanagiotisKanavos , I added \r\n at the end of the string that is sent by the server and reverted the client read function to ReadLineAsync. Now Client is reading as soon as the data is sent to the pipe.

Comment: Just `\n` is enough

Comment: Thanks, \n worked as well.